# Combining OSPFv2 with Static route

Tags: routing, ospf

Based on this topology : https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8XTG.jpg

My question is:

> 1) Can OSPF and static route work together? IS there conflict if i
>   were to configured a static route from R1 to R3 directly.
>
> 2) If R1 to R3 best route is R1->R2->R3. And I configured a static
>   route from R1 to R3 directly. Which route would it still take?
>   R1->R2-R3? or R1-R3?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is yes OSPF and static route can work together using command on CISCO

redistributed connected subnet

The 2nd answer yes you can give static route between R1 > R3 provided they should be connected to the area 0, and satic route will be best as its AD value is 1 and OSPF is 110 lower is better

hail network and if you find useful please click correct

Comment: So the purpose of configuring Static route in a already configured OSPFv2 network is just to have AD value of 1 so that it would be the preferred path to go?

Comment: Static route is given your all router has a same gateway at that time it is tedious to advertise each route at that time simple static route is given.         ip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0 default gateway